# Appending extra elements to existing string of html in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom-manipulation

I need to dynamically append a header and footer to specific elements of an HTML web page in Node.js but I'm not sure how to do it. I have a function that takes html as a string and options that may or may not contain extra strings for header and footer content.

The idea is that if either a header or footer is passed into the function it will be appended to the existing HTML appropriately.

Here is what the function looks like. I am using lodash to test if there is header/footer content. I'd like to perform the append inside the `if` block. I've had a look at cheerio but not sure if it can be used on html if it's in a string.Thanks for any help in advance!

```
function generator(html, options) {

    var header = _.get(options, 'partials.header');
    var footer = _.get(options, 'partials.footer');


  // Check if either header of footer options.partials
    if(header || footer) {
      console.log('YEAH! ::: ', header);
      // Append header and/or footer to the HTML here

    }
}
```

Comment: The very first example in the Cheerio README shows how to parse HTML that's in a string. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Answer (score 0):

How about concatenating the strings?

```
function generator(html, options) {

    var header = _.get(options, 'partials.header') || '';
    var footer = _.get(options, 'partials.footer') || '';


    // Check if either header of footer options.partials
    if (header || footer) {
      html = (header + html + footer);
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion which works fine in that context. The problem is the header and footer must be inside the html, which is a complete web page and be appended at specific points. For example, the header should be appended as an immediate childNode of a page wrapper div. Sorry I didn't make it clearer.

Comment: @mikeym How about adding placeholders in the html, and then using a regular expression to swap the header/footer in at those points?